# Multithreaded versions result differs from non multithreaded version

Tags: multithreading, scala

I am practicing multithreading. I have an array of values that I want to filter based on a predicate. The result should keep the original order. Example where values above 2 are kept:

```
(1, 5, 2, 7, 4) -> (5, 7, 4)
```

The multithreaded version I have sometimes skips the last chunk and always leaves some values out of the end. The program takes two parameters and uses a TreeMap to keep track of the filtered values and their order.

```scala
def filter(array: Array[Int], pred: Int => Boolean): Array[Int] = {
  val treeMap = scala.collection.mutable.TreeMap[Int, Int]()  // ._1 Original index, ._2 Actual value

...

}
```

Let's say that I have `n = 100 000` and 12 cores available. That gives us `(100 000 / 12).ceil = 8334` entries per chunk. I figured that I could create the chunks as ranges of indices:

```scala
val entriesPerChunk = ((n * 1.00) / (cores * 1.00)).ceil.toInt  // 8334
var ranges = scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[Range]()

for(i <- 0 until cores)  {
      ranges = ranges :+ (0 + (entriesPerChunk * i) until (entriesPerChunk + (entriesPerChunk * i)))
}
```

Now I have ranges from `0 until 8334` to `91674 until 100008` so barely more than is needed.

A variable is created to make sure that all the entries are processed:

```scala
var totalCollected = 0
```

The forks themselves contain the following task:

```scala
val collectedValues = x collect array.zipWithIndex
totalCollected += collectedValues.size
collectedValues.filter(y => pred(y._1)).foreach(z => treeMap.put(z._2, z._1))
```

The above is done for every range (x) found in ranges. This aims to filter the range given for that thread based on the actual value of the entry (y._1). The acceptable values are then added to the treeMap with their indices (z._2) as the key so that the order remains.

Then the forks are joined and the resulting TreeMap is transformed to an array. I also separate the indices from the values here:

```scala
treeMap.toArray.map(_._2)
```

The end result is not what's expected. Sometimes totalCollected amounts to n, sometimes it's missing the last 8334 values. The final array is always missing some values from the end.

I then created a non multithreaded version based on the logic above:

```scala
def filter(array: Array[Int], pred: Int => Boolean): Array[Int] = {
  val treeMap = scala.collection.mutable.TreeMap[Int, Int]()  // ._1 Original index, ._2 Actual value
  array.zipWithIndex.filter(x => pred(x._1)).foreach(y => treeMap.put(y._2, y._1))
  treeMap.toArray.map(_._2)
}
```

This code functions as expected. What causes the discrepancy between the two versions?

Comment: That is why usually you should not use `var` in Scala. `totalCollected += collectedValues.size` is definitely not an atomic operation. You can either synchronize the access to it or return number of processed items from each fork and sum those numbers.

Comment: Thanks, the same atomicity issue existed with the treeMap. I placed a temporary treeMap within the tasks and then joined them when synchronizing the tasks. The code now functions.

Answer (score 0):

Based on a comment to the original post, two changes were made. The tasks now include a temporary map that holds the values from that specific range:

```scala
val tempMap = scala.collection.mutable.TreeMap[Int, Int]()
val collectedValues = x collect array.zipWithIndex
collectedValues.filter(y => pred(y._1)).foreach(z => tempMap.put(z._2, z._1))
tempMap
```

When synchronizing the forks, each tempMap is added to the original treeMap which is finally transformed into an array like in the original question.

This way atomicity does not become an issue.